# How can i style the Countdown Element from react-coundown-now?

Tags: reactjs, styles, countdown

I use the react-countdown-now component. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-now/v/1.0.0

I use it like this:

```
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';

function Component() {
  return (
    <Countdown date='2020-02-01T01:02:03' style={{ color: '#00ff00' }}/>
  );
}
```

I wonder how i can style this component, beacause the style tag doesn't affect something.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should style the rendered component or target styling span selector:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const PurpleCount = styled.div`
  span {
    color: purple;
  }
`;

// Random component
const Finished = () => (
  <span style={{ color: 'blue' }}>You are good to go!</span>
);

// Renderer callback
const renderer = ({ total, hours, minutes, seconds }) => {
  if (total) {
    // Render a countdown
    return (
      <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
        {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
      </span>
    );
  } else {
    // Render a finished state
    return <Finished />;
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Countdown date={Date.now() + 10000} renderer={renderer} />
    <br />
    <PurpleCount>
      <Countdown date={Date.now() + 10000} />
    </PurpleCount>
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit happy-cdn-ggnzf]

Answer (score -1):

Pass the style as a props of the Countdown component

```
return (
    <Countdown date='2020-02-01T01:02:03' styleColor={'#00ff00'}/>
  );
```

In Countdown component get the props and set the style of the parent div.
Goto Countdonw component and apply the below code

```
 <div className="App" style={{ color: this.state.styleColor }}>
```

Comment: You can check the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-clarke-zjkpj

Comment: Could you mention why this answer is useless?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the library as mentioned in the OP question, you showed a generic way to pass style